# Initialize pointer member in struct with array of ints

Tags: c++

I have an `int*` member in my struct. I want to initialize this member while initializing the struct, without having to resort to a temp array:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int*   arrInts;
};

MyStruct m = {
    {1, 2}              // Nor does compound literals work: (int[]){2, 4, 6}
};
```

This throws an error in MSVC 2019. So a temp `int` array wont be created by the compiler.

This struct is used to pass arguments to a DLL function, so I am trying to avoid STL classes object to be passed across the DLL boundary. The number of elements are not known beforehand so I can't declare a fixed size array as a struct member.

Regd the DLL function, it will simply store the passed data into a class member. The class is declared and used inside the DLL. I will use a std::vector there of course. I just want to avoid it at the DLL boundary/API and using basic types.

What are my alternatives?

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<int> arrInts;` as a member instead of `int*`. Raw pointers shouldn't be used when they point to objects they own.

Comment: Compound literals are allowed in C but not C++.

Comment: The compound literal variation works for me with g++.  It works for me in C if I change `MyStruct m =` to `struct MyStruct m =`.

Comment: Do you in fact need `MyStruct.arrInts` to be a pointer?  Could it be an array, instead? or a `std::vector`, as was already suggested?

Comment: This struct is used to pass arguments to a DLL function, so avoiding STL classes across DLL boundary. The number of elements are not known beforehand.

Comment: Solutions a) write a constructor for mystruct, which takes an initializer list as parameter and allocates and initializes arrInts b) write a layout-compatible replacement class to arrInts c) write a wrapper class around MyStruct, in which MyStruct is a (public?) member variable and the wrapper class could have a separate std::vector inside and keep arrInts up-to-date

Comment: d) derive from MyStruct, each derived class can be also used as a base class and put additional logic and members there (otherwise similar to c)

Comment: @safe_malloc It would really help if we had the that DLL function.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I am trying the alternatives now.

Comment: In what kind do you produce the array content? You pass it as curly brace initializer to MyStruct. Is it constant there or dynamically put together? Is the size known at each call, but not generally constant or even unknown at each call? Will the DLL definitely just make a copy or would you consider keeping the ownership in the caller with the DLL just referring to the memory to save the copy. Or would it be architectural effort to keep the MyStruct in memory, because it is a local object and just used for calling the DLL.

Comment: Is the array size small (a few parameters) or large? Would the DLL later on change the number of elements internally (you said, you would use a vector) or is it only to cope with unknown size.

Comment: For testing the function, I am currently hard coding the array values while declaring the struct. In production, I will read them from a file. Yes, the DLL will make a copy, so the array needs to last only till the end of the calling function. The array size will be less than a thousand but not there yet. The template parameter pack works for me, thanks. Learnt a few things there. I guess there will considerable expansion of the template with that many elements so with a large number of elements, I might need to consider a different approach later!

Comment: With so many (dynamically generated) elements, the second shown approach (d) could get suitable (its advantage in comparison to b, you can store more than just a pointer, to get more functionality): approach d currently stores the data with `new int[]` in a `std::shared_ptr`, but could be modified to use a `std::vector` with `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: But you could also just implement a function, which calls the DLL in turn and gets two input parameters, an incomplete `MyStruct` (without `arrInts` - set to `nullptr`) and a `std::vector<int> v`. The function copies the pointer to the first element `&v[0]` into `arrInts` and calls the DLL. After the call to the DLL the `arrInts` is set to `nullptr` again for safety reasons, as the corresponding `vector` could be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, yes that sounds like an interesting option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is solution b: A compatible replacement for `int*`.

In this version I disabled the copy constructor and copy assignment altogether. If you want to copy, you have to decide and specify what happens with the arrInts array (e.g. should another array be allocated or the pointer should point at the same array).

The arrInts pointer can be accessed as `m.arrInts` and the elements as `m.arrInts[0]`. So everything normal. There is an implicit conversion operator to (in this case) `int*` defined.

You can send the MyStruct to the DLL. At the other side (if also implemented by you) you would define MyStruct with an `int*` type for the array.

The CompatArray has one pointer as member variable, which is put at the correct position in the MyStruct. So the layout is identical.

The array is created on the heap, when MyStruct is constructed, and the pointer is stored in the MyStruct. As soon as the MyStruct object goes out of scope, the MyStruct object is deleted together at the same time as the array.

```
template <typename T>
struct CompatArray {
    template <typename... Types>
    CompatArray(Types... l) : a(new T[]{ l... }) {};
    ~CompatArray() { delete[] a; };
    CompatArray(const CompatArray& m) = delete;
    CompatArray& operator=(const CompatArray& other) = delete;
    operator T*() { return a; };

    T* a;
};

struct MyStruct {
    int w;
    float x;
    CompatArray<int> arrInts;
    double y;
};
    
int main() {
    MyStruct m = {4, .5f, { 4, 1, 2 }, 9.};
}
```

That is solution d: Derive from `MyStruct`

Advantages: The `std::shared_ptr` provides copy and move semantics. Copies share the same `arrInts` array. The `shared_ptr` keeps track of a usage counter.

The derived struct `MySuperStruct` can be used as a `MyStruct`. The additional member variable `s` for the `shared_ptr` is added to the end of the class. `arrInts` keeps a copy of the raw pointer.

It is possible to overwrite the array with `store()` or do it only for copies. This is all handled by the `shared_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>

struct MyStruct {
    int w;
    float x;
    int* arrInts;
    double y;
};

struct MySuperStruct : public MyStruct {
    template <typename... Types>
    MySuperStruct(Types... l) : MyStruct(l...) {};

    template <typename... Types>
    void store(Types... l) {
        s = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int[]{ l... }, std::default_delete<int[]>());
        arrInts = s.get();
    };

    std::shared_ptr<int> s;
};

extern "C" void callDll(MyStruct* m);

int main() {
    MySuperStruct m = {4, .5f, nullptr, 9.};
    m.store(4, 1, 2);
    m.store(5, 0, -8, 6);
    MySuperStruct m2 = m;
    callDll(&m);
}
```

Comment: Tried the first approach, works with MSVC 2019, version 16.10.4

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that you can't do it in C++.

You can do this in C (C99 or newer) using a compound literal:

```
struct s {
    int *data;
};

struct s m = {(int[]){1, 2, 3}};
```

However, even in C this is can be error prone.  E.g. this won't work:

```
struct s make_s(void) {
  struct s m = {(int[]){1, 2, 3}};
  return m;
}
```

Why?  The `m.data` pointer points to an int array that lives only as long as the `make_s` call.

Regardless, compound literals do not exist in C++, and [this gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) explains why g++ will normally reject code that uses it.  Notably:

> In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or automatic storage duration. In C++, a compound literal designates a temporary object, which only lives until the end of its full-expression. As a result, well-defined C code that takes the address of a subobject of a compound literal can be undefined in C++, [...]

This hints at what you need to think about with whatever solution you eventually end up with. The lifetime of the `data` member needs to be at least as long as the struct itself. In C++, this is usually taken care of with classes that use containers, smart pointers, etc. If you need to bridge to a C (or C-like) API I think you'll need to take care of the lifetime details explicitly in code.

Comment: Thanks, yes that clears up the compound literals part.